# Many-to-Many: sequelize doesn't create methods

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, sequelize.js

Consider two models `User` and `Project` with the relation Many-To-Many.

When I try this: `db.User.getProjects()` I get an error

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getProjects()'

I've read in the docs this method should be generated automatically
So why I get this error?

### Source Code:

project.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Project.hasMany(models.User);
            }
        }
    })

    return Project
}
```

user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {}, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.Project),
                User.belongsTo(models.Boss, {
                    foreignKey: 'user_id'
                })
            }
        }
    })

    return User
}
```

Comment: Can you add your model code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because db.User is the model, and not the instance.

the getAccessor() methods are invoked upon instances. You should do something like:

```
db.User
    .find( {where: {user_id: user_id}} )
    .then(function(user) {
        return user.getProjects();
    })
    .then(function(projects) {
        //do something with your projects DAO
    })
    .catch(function(err) {});
```

It is the instance, or the DAO that is returned from your first `db.User.find` that has the methods.